# Python None variables usage

Tags: python

Is there any way to simplify the following code:

```
def get_or_create_user(id, photo=None, first_name=None, last_name=None, nickname=None, organization=None, city=None, country=None):
    ... # save user in the datastore

class UserCreationHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        id = self.request.get('id')
        photo = None
        first_name = None
        last_name = None
        nickname = None
        organization = None
        city = None
        country = None
        if something1:
            # do some calculations
            if something2:
                # do some other calculations
                if something3:
                    # assign id, photo, first_name etc. values 
        get_or_create_user(id, photo, first_name, last_name, nickname, organization, city, country)
```

I don't like these assignments to None.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
def get(self):
    id = self.request.get('id')
    user_details = {}
    if something:
        # assign user_details['id'], user_details['photo'], user_details['first_name'] etc. values
    get_or_create_user(id, **user_details)
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of these `**`?

Comment: @LA_ `**` expands a `dict` to named arguments when calling a function. Similarly, `*` expands a `list` for positional arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing that `get_or_create_user` uses default arguments set to `None`:

```
def get_or_create_user(id, photo=None, first_name=None, last_name=None, nickname=None, organization=None, city=None, country=None):
```

You can just use this:

```
class UserCreationHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        id = self.request.get('id')
        if something:
            # set stuff ...
            # and then call get_or_create_user(...)
        else:
            get_or_create_user(id)
```

Comment: Sorry, actually there are more IF conditions - I've updated the code.